# Help with expectation question

Tags: probability, expectation

I have the problem:

A fair coin is tossed $n$ times. The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are defined by:

$X=$number of heads in the first $k$ tosses $(k<n)$

$Y=$number of heads in all $n$ tosses

The random variable $Z$ is $Y-X$. I must firstly work out the expected value of each random variable so I have worked it out as:

$E(X)=\frac k2$

$E(Y)=\frac n2$

And now I am not sure what $E(Z)$ would be? Would it simply be $\frac {n-k}{2}$?

I then must find $E(XZ)$ and hence $E(XY)$. Can anyone provide any help with this? If I have $E(Z)$ I am sure I could do it as I know that the random variables are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes $E(Z)=\frac {n-k}{2}$ as you can add and subtract expectations appropriately without worrying about independence

$X$ and $Z$ are independent so $E[XZ]=E[X]E[Z]$,

so $E[XY] = E[XX]+E[XZ]$ leaving you with a further calculation of $E\left[X^2\right]$

Comment: I must state that the question then asks: "Why is it not the case that $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$?" So I presume that means they are not independent since $k$ depends on $n$ as it cannot be larger than $n$.

Comment: @Dan He computed $E[XZ]$, not $E[XY]$. The variables $X$ and $Z$ are independent, but $X$ and $Y$ are not.

Comment: Ah I see now, of course

Comment: How could I calculate $E(X^2)$ without knowing any X values?

Comment: You have a binomial random variable.  $Var(X)=k/4$ and $E[X^2]=k(k+1)/4$